# Sub report in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i am having subreport in the crystal report i want to disable that particular sub report in the crystal report.How to do this?any example?

Comment: `CrystalReportViewer.EnableDrillDown = false;`? The question is not at all clear.

Comment: i need to disable a sub report for a condition during  run time  how to do this/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main report right click on the sub report you want to disable.
Click on Format Object and then from Common tab click on the icon just right to 'Suppress' checkbox.

In the opening editor write the condition under which you want it to be disable.
For example:

```
 {MyTable.MyField} = TheConditionalValue
```

In the same way you can do it on the containing section.
Go to 'Section Expert...', select the section containing your subreport, click on the icon right to 'Suppress' and do the same as before.